# Почему не сохраняется поле содержащие кавычки

Tags: php, mysql

```
$csv = $_POST['csv'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO csv (unicode, content) VALUES ('$unicode', '$csv')");
```

content это TEXT запись.
csv держит в себе csv контент поэтому в нем имеются знаки ", думаю как раз из-за них проблема с записью. после выполнения query значение content == NULL

Так как-же правильно записать контент csv в запись TEXT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правы. Вам стоит прочитать про [экранирование](http://www.phpfaq.ru/slashes).

Comment: addCslashes($_POST['csv'], '"'); Не спасло, еще идеи?

Comment: @Awesome, есть ещё идея - не сразу строку пихать в запрос, а вывести на экран и посмотреть, что же там всё-таки происходит. А ещё лучше весь запрос.

А вообще, только что заметил - используйте addslashes вместо addcslashes. Второй экранирует все спецсимволы, а не по списку

Comment: addslashes - тоже самое
если показывать echo, показывает строчки такого плана:
\"\";\"\";\"\"

csv генерися с помощью jQuery table2CSV

Comment: @Awesome сюда выведите запрос, либо пишите подробне